# php GD library error in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 11.04 and when I am opening terminal and typing `php -a` it is showing some error like this

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I think there is some problem with GD library.Is there any option to solve it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yeah. Just try:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

You probably will have to remove the offending line in your php.ini, either in php.ini or in 
/etc/php5/conf.d/gd.ini maybe.

Comment: Alternate solution, if you don't need the `php5-gd` package, is to purge it: `sudo apt-get purge php5-gd`

Comment: If you are using php 7.3 in Ubuntu 18.04 us `sudo apt install php7.3-gd`

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like

```
sudo apt-get install php-gd
```

should do it, if not try

```
apt-cache search php | grep gd
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was:

```
locate --regex /mcrypt[.]so\$ /gd[.]so\$ /suhosin[.]so\$ /pdo_mysql.so\$ /pdo[.]so /mysqli[.]so\$ '/php5/.*/mysql[.]so$'
```

Which returned the location of all the libraries that my php5 install was having trouble finding:

```
/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/gd.so
/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mcrypt.so
/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mysql.so
/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mysqli.so
/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/pdo.so
/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/pdo_mysql.so
```

I was a little worried that these look they might be old versions, but I used their paths anyway. Stefgosselin identified the location of the ini files, `/etc/php5/conf.d/`. I modified them all. The command below will modify **all** of the `*.ini` files there, so make sure all of yours really need modifying. Obviously you need to use the target path you discovered with the locate command in place of mine, `/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/`:

```
 sudo sed -ri -e "s|^(extension=)(\w{2,10}[.]so)$|\1/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/\2|g" /etc/php5/conf.d/*.ini
```

Before finding this solution I tried several `apt-get purge` and `apt-get reinstall` commands without luck. I'm not sure, but my problem may have originated with installation of zend from source or phpmyadmin with aptitude. It never caused any php errors, just the annoying warning you mentioned. Finally php5 can launch without errors:

`php5 --version`

gives ...

```
PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: May  2 2011 23:18:30)  Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Suhosin v0.9.32.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2010, by SektionEins GmbH
```

Comment: Although your solution *does* do the trick, you gave yourself a lot of trouble. Simply removing the offending line in gd.ini and reinstalling the latest gd binary would of also done the trick. But hey, I +1'ed your solution for the sed usage! Happy coding buddy, thanks for contributing.

Comment: @stefgosselin, I may have tried that before the more complicated solution, but will try again to make sure. Thanks. Thanks for upvote too.

Comment: On little addition, if you're using php5-fpm you'll need to restart it, e.g. `sudo service php5-fpm restart`

Comment: Ok this solution does what it says but not necessarily solves the problem. I had the same scenario as yours but the command you provide effectively changes the affected files indisde of /etc/php5/conf.d but it made some other things stop working. Maybe I missed out something?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt install php-gd` will work but the thing is it will download the plugin for the latest PHP version.

If your PHP version is not the latest, then you can add version in it:

```
# PHP 7.1
sudo apt install php7.1-gd

# PHP 7.2:
sudo apt install php7.2-gd

# PHP 7.3
sudo apt install php7.3-gd

# PHP 7.4 (latest)
sudo apt install php-gd
```