# magento2 bin/magento not working

Tags: php, magento

> prince_admin@testingwithdb:~/magento2$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd2' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/gd2 (/usr/lib/php/20170718/gd2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/gd2.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/gd2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
> Deprecated Functionality: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in /var/www/html/prince/magento2/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 81

As above, i can not use bin/magento to add my new created module..
Can anyone kindly help me?

Comment: Can you please provide some context to your question?! What have you tried to solve the problem? Probably some minimal, reproducable code for your problem would help. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a problem with Magento but with PHP. 
You're missing the gd2 library.

try the following (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148679/php-gd-library-error-in-ubuntu)):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```